# Перенести Unity Text на текстуру

Tags: c#, unity3d, photoshop, render, текстура

Я делаю оооочень простой "фоторедактор". У меня есть **текстура - задний фон**, и **поверх** неё пользователь должен написать какой-то **текст**. В результате мой класс/скрипт должен сохранить изображение с наложенным текстом поверх (с расширением заранее выбранным пользователем).

*(ну тип как в фотошопе)*

Каким образом это можно сделать?

Comment: Не буду говорить, насколько абсурдна идея делать фоторедактор на игровом движке. Для решения задачи можно использовать render texture.

Comment: это не фоторедактор, это малюсенький кусок приложения, ну надо, не переносить же мне всё на xamarin

Comment: Так я же не заставляю вас отказываться от этой идеи, так, мысли вслух. Просто тащить за собой вещь движок ради вставки текста в картинку - это все равно, что ядерной бомбой тараканов истреблять. Оно не для того делалось и вы на своем пути еще много кочек можете из-за юнити собрать ;)